# Flex does not recognize patterns of type (?r-s:pattern)

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I have flex version 2.5.4 installed.

Whenever i input a flex program of the form:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
%%
(?i:foo) printf("foo found");
%%
```

I get unrecognized rule error on the line (?i:foo) ...

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pattern flags, you need to upgrade your version of flex. The pattern syntax `(?i:...)` was added in version 2.5.35 (but you might as well update to the current version, 2.5.39).

Note: ubuntu has two flex packages: `flex` and `flex-old`. Logically, `flex-old` is an older version of `flex` (2.5.4, in fact). I don't know under what circumstances an ubuntu installation will contain the outdated flex, but if you find yourself with `flex-old` installed, you should be able to replace it with `flex` using `apt-get install`.

Comment: The latest version is 2.5.4 and I have it installed on Ubuntu.

Comment: Actually, the latest version is 2.5.39, but it's not available for all versions of ubuntu. 2.5.35 is; see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=flex&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all . If your ubuntu is really old, you may need to update flex manually.

Comment: I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.

Entering "flex --version" in terminal gives 

    "flex version 2.5.4"

Comment: @AbhayMittal: Then you have the package `flex-old` installed (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/flex-old) and you need to install the package `flex` (http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/flex)